# BCP Error Invalid field size for datatype With Native Method

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I keep getting the "Invalid field size for datatype" error trying to BCP in several tables. This is despite the fact that I'm using Native (Unicode) mode and I am absolutely certain that the table definitions match because the target is created from a DACPAC of the source right before I attempt the import. Some tables work, but most fail with the error. I've tried using format files as well, and that didn't help either. I've read all the documentation and all the BCP-related questions I could find on SO. Any ideas?

Here's my export command. The $query_array is just a dictionary of "Select * From $tbl" mixed with "Select * From $tbl Where *some date filter*":

```
&bcp $query_array[$tbl] QueryOut "Data\$tbl.dat" -N -S $SqlAddress -d $SqlDB -T;
```

And here's the import:

```
&bcp $tgtTable in "Data\$tbl.dat" -N -S $SqlAddress -d $SqlDB -E -T -ErrorAction Stop;
```

One of the tables that fails looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo].[Bar](
    [Blah1] [numeric](38, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Blah2] [numeric](38, 0) NULL,
    [Blah3] [numeric](38, 0) NULL,
    [Blah4] [numeric](38, 0) NULL,
    [Blah5] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Blah6] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Blah7] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Blah1] ASC
)
```

The overall procedure is pretty simple

1. Generate DACPAC from source
2. Export each table using BCP in Unicode Native to a dat file
3. Create target DB from DACPAC
4. Import each table using BCP in Unicode Native format from dat file

This is driving me crazy. It should *just work*. I'm guessing that there's a problem with the datetime2 fields, but I cant imagine what it is. TIA.

Comment: What happens if you remove `-ErrorAction Stop`? This has no (good) effect, since `bcp` is a native command and does not support PowerShell common parameters. As a result it just ends up passed to `bcp` and I have no idea what it does with it.

Comment: "Native" is not a Unicode mode, it's raw/binary mode. Have you confirmed that the table schema is identical between the source table you export the data from versus the destination table you're trying to import the data into?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: `-N` is called "Unicode native" format by the `bcp` docs itself. It is only "raw" for non-text types while text types are transferred as Unicode even if they are originally `[VAR]CHAR`.

Comment: Without the ErrorAction=Stop, it was failing silently and we thought all the data was getting loaded when in fact it was only partially finished. Jeroen is correct about the -N flag, it is Unicode Native. We had issues with some of our data when we tried the non-unicode native (little -n). Yes the table schema is identical, the target is created from a DACPAC of the source. Thx.